# Why isn't my JQuery custom selector working?

Tags: jquery

I've created a selector plugin called "containsExactly" that, as you would expect, is meant to filter elements that contain exactly the supplied text:

```
(function($){
    $.extend($.expr[":"],{
        containsExactly: function(element, index, matches, set){
            var text= matches[3];
            if ($(element).text() == text){
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I then tried to integrate my custom selector into a larger selection for the purpose of hiding all table rows who's fourth table cell does not exactly contain a supplied string of text:

```
$("#news").find("tr").has("td").not(function(){
    return $(this).children(":nth-child(4):containsExactly("+ topic +")");
}).hide();
```

But it has no effect on the table's rows and I am stumped. Can anyone see what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

***Update: I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BnTnN/3/ The first row should be visible and the second should be hidden.***

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML, impossible to tell if that selector will have any effect.

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BRU5Z/

Comment: Would creating it on `$` with the standard clash protection wrapper around it, mean that it does not exist outside of that wrapper.  ie. is `$` local to that block, and is your usage outside of it?

Comment: @Orbling: no, that would not be a problem, both point at the same object. Otherwise, many plugins would also not work.

Comment: @RenéWolferink: Well, the point about the plugins not working doesn't necessarily follow.  But having looked it up, objects are always passed with a reference, so it would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/BRU5Z/5/

The JS is:

```
$("#news").find("tr").has("td").not(function(){
    var elem = $(this).children(":nth-child(4):containsExactly("+ topic +")");
    return elem.length ? elem : '';
}).hide();
```

I think it's because one instance of `$(this).children(":nth-child(4):containsExactly("+ topic +")")` was returning `undefined` and messing up the `.not()` function.

Comment: This works! TYVM Joe! The moral to the story: Build in error checking. :)

Comment: @user1791841 - no problem :) it wasn't an obvious error so I just added a few checks inside `.not(function(){...` to see exactly what was being returned.